# Html with does not cover 100% width of the page on mobile display

Tags: html, css

Trying to find the bug on my css style sheet. I'm not sure why my html is not covering 100% of the page. See below screenshots:

[image: Phone inspect]

The gap on the bigger screen is smaller but still annoying. See css below:

[image]

```
/*
=============== 
Fonts
===============
*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@200;300;400;500;700&display=swap');

/*
=============== 
Variables
===============
*/

:root {
    --clr-primary-1: rgb(41, 41, 41);
    --clr-primary-3: hsl(185, 81%, 29%);
    --clr-white: #fff;
    --ff-primary: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    --transition: all 0.3s linear;
    --spacing: 0.1rem;
    --radius: 0.5rem;
    --light-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    --dark-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
/*
=============== 
Global Styles
===============
*/

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
body {
    font-family: var(--ff-primary);
    background: var(--clr-white);
    color: var(--clr-primary-1);
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--clr-primary-1);
}
img {
    width: 60%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

/*  global classes */

.section-center {
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* 
=============== 
NavBar - header 
===============
*/

nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background: var(--clr-white);
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    box-shadow: var(--dark-shadow);
}


.header-title {
    font-weight: 500;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

=============== 
Main Banner 
===============
*/

.main-banner {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 85vh;
    background: url('../images//USoA-Homepage-Block-3.webp') center/cover
        no-repeat;
    align-items: center;
}

/* 
=============== 
SHOP ALL SECTION 
===============
*/

.collections {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: var(--spacing);
    padding: 50px 0;
}

=============== 
ABOUT US 
===============
*/

.about-us {
    color: var(--clr-white);
    background: var(--clr-primary-1);
    display: flex;
    display: block;
}

=============== 
PRODUCT
===============
*/

.products-holder {
    padding: 1rem 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(350px, 1fr));
    justify-items: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <title>Rainbow Sodas UK</title>
        <!-- favicon -->
        <link
            rel="shortcut icon"
            href="./images//favicon.ico"
            type="image/x-icon"
        />
        <!-- font-awesome -->
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="./fontawesome-free-5.12.1-web/css/all.min.css"
        />
        <!-- styles css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css" />
        <!-- Script -->
        <script src="./js/app.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header id="home">
            <nav>
                <button type="button" class="nav-toggle" id="nav-toggle">
                    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                <h1 class="header-title">RAINBOW SODAS UK</h1>
                <button type="button" class="nav-toggle" id="cart-drawer-toggle">
                    <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"
                        ><span class="cart-items-counter">0</span></i
                    >
                </button>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <main>
            <div class="side-menu" id="side-menu">
                <button type="button" id="drawer-close" class="drawer-menu-close">
                    <i class="far fa-window-close"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="drawer-title">SODAS UK</div>
                <ul class="nav-links">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#products-filter" class="nav-link">shop all</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#products-filter" class="nav-link">products</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#about" class="nav-link">about us</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="cart-drawer" id="cart-drawer">
                <div class="cart-inner">
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        id="cart-drawer-close"
                        class="cart-drawer-close"
                    >
                        <i class="far fa-window-close"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="cart-drawer-title">CART</div>
                    <section class="cart-items-list">
                        <article class="cart-item">
                            <div class="side-cart-product-item">
                                <h3>product 1</h3>
                                <button class="trash-icon">
                                    <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="side-cart-product-price">
                                <p>$40</p>
                                <div class="cart-qty">
                                    <button class="qty-btn">-</button>
                                    <span>0</span>
                                    <button class="qty-btn">+</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                    </section>
                </div>
                <div cart="cart-footer">
                    <div class="total-display-side-cart">
                        <h3>total</h3>
                        <span>$120</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkout-drawer">
                        <button>checkout</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main-banner">
                <div class="banner-text">
                    <h1>
                        Welcome to <br /><strong
                            >the rainbow <br />uk <br />sodas company
                        </strong>
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="collections">
                <a href="#products-filter" class="shop-all"
                    >shop all <span><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></span
                ></a>
            </div>
            <section class="section-center" id="about">
                <div class="about-us">
                    <h1>WE THE PEOPLE BEHIND CRAFTED <br />SODAS IN <br />UK</h1>
                    <p>
                        In order for a more perfect beverage, establish variety, insure
                        palatable tranquility, provide for the extraordinary taste, promote
                        the general refreshment and secure the blessings of flavor to
                        ourselves and our posterity do ordain and establish this soda
                        company for the people of UK.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section class="section-center" id="products-filter">
                <div class="products">
                    <h1>SHOP THE <br />FLAVOURS</h1>
                </div>
                <button class="toggle-filter" id="toggle-category-filters">
                    filter
                    <span id="filter-btn-span"><i class="far fa-minus-square"></i></span>
                </button>
                <div class="categories-holder" id="categories-holder">
                    <button class="filter-btn" type="button" value="Berry">berry</button>
                    <button class="filter-btn" type="button" value="Berry">
                        citrusy
                    </button>
                    <button class="filter-btn" type="button" value="Berry">
                        classic
                    </button>
                    <button class="filter-btn" type="button" value="Berry">fancy</button>
                    <button class="filter-btn" type="button" value="Berry">floral</button>
                    <button class="filter-btn" type="button" value="Berry">jazzy</button>
                    <button class="filter-btn" type="button" value="Berry">juicy</button>
                    <button class="filter-btn" type="button" value="Berry">sour</button>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section class="products-holder" id="products-holder">
                <article class="single-product">
                    <div class="product-image-container">
                        <img src="images/Cherry_Pop_Still_4K_Front-CherryPop.png" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-title">
                        <h2>CHERRY POP</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cart-btn-holder">
                        <button class="add-to-cart-btn" id="add-to-cart">
                            add to cart
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article class="single-product">
                    <div class="product-image-container">
                        <img
                            class="tour-img"
                            src="images/Cherry_Pop_Still_4K_Front-CherryPop.png"
                            alt=""
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-title">
                        <h2>CHERRY POP</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cart-btn-holder">
                        <button class="add-to-cart-btn" id="add-to-cart">
                            add to cart
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article class="single-product">
                    <div class="product-image-container">
                        <img
                            class="tour-img"
                            src="images/Cherry_Pop_Still_4K_Front-CherryPop.png"
                            alt=""
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-title">
                        <h2>CHERRY POP</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cart-btn-holder">
                        <button class="add-to-cart-btn" id="add-to-cart">
                            add to cart
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article class="single-product">
                    <div class="product-image-container">
                        <img
                            class="tour-img"
                            src="images/Cherry_Pop_Still_4K_Front-CherryPop.png"
                            alt=""
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-title">
                        <h2>CHERRY POP</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cart-btn-holder">
                        <button class="add-to-cart-btn" id="add-to-cart">
                            add to cart
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </article>

                <article class="single-product">
                    <div class="product-image-container">
                        <img
                            class="tour-img"
                            src="images/Cherry_Pop_Still_4K_Front-CherryPop.png"
                            alt=""
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-title">
                        <h2>CHERRY POP</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cart-btn-holder">
                        <button class="add-to-cart-btn" id="add-to-cart">
                            add to cart
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article class="single-product">
                    <div class="product-image-container">
                        <img
                            class="tour-img"
                            src="images/Cherry_Pop_Still_4K_Front-CherryPop.png"
                            alt=""
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-title">
                        <h2>CHERRY POP</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cart-btn-holder">
                        <button class="add-to-cart-btn" id="add-to-cart">
                            add to cart
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article class="single-product">
                    <div class="product-image-container">
                        <img
                            class="tour-img"
                            src="images/Cherry_Pop_Still_4K_Front-CherryPop.png"
                            alt=""
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-title">
                        <h2>CHERRY POP</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cart-btn-holder">
                        <button class="add-to-cart-btn" id="add-to-cart">
                            add to cart
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article class="single-product">
                    <div class="product-image-container">
                        <img
                            class="tour-img"
                            src="images/Cherry_Pop_Still_4K_Front-CherryPop.png"
                            alt=""
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-title">
                        <h2>CHERRY POP</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cart-btn-holder">
                        <button class="add-to-cart-btn" id="add-to-cart">
                            add to cart
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article class="single-product">
                    <div class="product-image-container">
                        <img
                            class="tour-img"
                            src="images/Cherry_Pop_Still_4K_Front-CherryPop.png"
                            alt=""
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-title">
                        <h2>CHERRY POP</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cart-btn-holder">
                        <button class="add-to-cart-btn" id="add-to-cart">
                            add to cart
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article class="single-product">
                    <div class="product-image-container">
                        <img
                            class="tour-img"
                            src="images/Cherry_Pop_Still_4K_Front-CherryPop.png"
                            alt=""
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-title">
                        <h2>CHERRY POP</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cart-btn-holder">
                        <button class="add-to-cart-btn" id="add-to-cart">
                            add to cart
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </section>
            <!-- footer -->
            <footer class="section footer">
                <!-- footer links -->
                <ul class="footer-links">
                    <!-- single link -->
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="footer-link">home</a>
                    </li>
                    <!-- end of single link -->
                    <!-- single link -->
                    <li>
                        <a href="#about" class="footer-link">about</a>
                    </li>
                    <!-- end of single link -->
                    <!-- single link -->
                    <li>
                        <a href="#products-filter" class="footer-link">products</a>
                    </li>
                    <!-- end of single link -->
                </ul>
                <!-- end of footer links -->
                <!-- footer icons -->
                <ul class="footer-icons">
                    <!-- single icon -->
                    <li>
                        <a
                            href="https://www.twitter.com"
                            target="_blank"
                            class="footer-icon"
                        >
                            <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <!-- end of single icon -->
                    <!-- single icon -->
                    <li>
                        <a
                            href="https://www.twitter.com"
                            target="_blank"
                            class="footer-icon"
                        >
                            <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <!-- end of single icon -->
                    <!-- single icon -->
                    <li>
                        <a
                            href="https://www.twitter.com"
                            target="_blank"
                            class="footer-icon"
                        >
                            <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <!-- end of single icon -->
                </ul>
                <!-- end of footer icons -->
                <p class="copyright">
                    copyright &copy; carlos suarez <span id="date"></span>. all rights
                    reserved
                </p>
            </footer>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have checked the body class and the different classes that control the width but I can't find the problem. I have added the css classes where I think there could be a problem.

thanks!

Comment: hi. where your html?

Comment: That is because your text is too big and causes an overflow on the x axis

Comment: Just added the html! what do you mean ? @xDrago

Comment: This happens usually when you have a very big (as in font size) text like you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this css

```
html,body
   {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        overflow-x: hidden; 
    }
```

Comment: thanks! what was the issue. This could be good for learning :)

Comment: i think the issue was the elements in the HTML and body had more width than HTML and body and there was also a overflow so we put width 100% and overflow hidden